# Please explain what does "for xml path(''), TYPE) .value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')" do in this code

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, unpivot

**In this code I am converting the subjects(columns) English , Hindi , Sanskrith , into rows**

```
DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

 select @colsUnpivot 
               =stuff(
         (select ',' + quotename (C.name)
          from sys.columns c
          where c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.result2')
          for xml path(''), TYPE) .value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
        1, 8, ''
    );

print @colsunpivot

select  @query 
              = 'select Name, Subject,Marks
                 from result2
                 unpivot
                        (
                          marks for subject in (' + @colsunpivot + ')) as tab'

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

*Please explain what does* **for xml path(''), TYPE) .value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') do here .**

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A common technique for aggregate string concatenation before SQL Server 2017 is using XML data type methods along with `STUFF` to remove the extra delimiter. In SQL Server 2017 and later, [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) makes this task much cleaner and easier. The `STRING_AGG` equivalent:

```
select @colsUnpivot = STRING_AGG(quotename (C.name),',')
          from sys.columns c
          where c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.result2')
```

The components of the XML expression technique for aggregate string concatenation are as follows.

This subquery will generate a result set with one row per column in the source table with a comma preceding each column name:

```
select ',' + quotename (C.name)
          from sys.columns c
          where c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.result2')
```

Example result:

```
,[column1]
,[column2]
,[column3]
```

Adding the `FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE` converts these rows into a single strongly-typed XML text node with the concatenated rows, allowing XML methods like `value` to be used on the type:

```
select ',' + quotename (C.name)
          from sys.columns c
          where c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.result2')
for xml path(''), TYPE
```

Result (XML type):

```
,[column1],[column2],[column3]
```

Invoking the method `value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')` on that XML node converts the XML node to an nvarchar(MAX) string. The [`value` XML data type method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15) takes an XQuery expression with `'.'` representing the current node (only node here) and the second argument being the desired SQL data type to be returned.

```
SELECT
         (select ',' + quotename (C.name)
          from sys.columns c
          where c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.result2')
          for xml path(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
```

Result (nvarchar(MAX)):

```
,[column1],[column2],[column3]
```

Finally, the STUFF function removes the extraneous leading delimiter from the string. There is an error in your original example; the length should be 1 instead of 8 so that only the comma is removed:

```
SELECT
         STUFF((select ',' + quotename (C.name)
          from sys.columns c
          where c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.result2')
          for xml path(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
```

Final result (nvarchar(MAX)):

```
[column1],[column2],[column3]
```

I sometimes see folks omit the `, TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')` when using this technique. The problem with that is that some characters must be escaped with XML entity references (e.g; quotes) so the resultant string will not be as expected in that case.

**EDIT:**

Incorporating Mister Magoo's recommendation to use `(./text())[1]` instead of just `.` as the node spec, the query below will improve performance with large data sets.

```
SELECT
         STUFF((select ',' + quotename (C.name)
          from sys.columns c
          where c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.result2')
          for xml path(''), TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'');
```

Comment: in value('.',NVARCHAR(MAX)) what does '.' do ?

Comment: @HarishKumar, I added more info to my answer. Hopefully, it's now clearer.

Comment: Dan (and @HarishKumar ): Since this was part of the question, I would make it clearer that `, TYPE` returns the resulting XML (from the `FOR XML`) as an actual XML type such that the `value()` method can be called on that subquery, and without `, TYPE` the `FOR XML` will return the same thing but as `NVARCHAR(MAX)` which then would not allow for the `.value()` to be added.

Answer (score 6):

As [Dan said](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/207380/22336), but also...

Get in the habit of using the text() node in xml values, it won't make much difference to a small result set, but I see no reason to ever NOT use it, and you will really see a benefit in larger data sets.

The red section is painful and can be avoided by the use of (./text())[1]

[image: Compare plans with use of text() node.]